# LaTeX in math blogging

Tags: formatting

I'm wondering if anybody has advice about using LaTeX in math blogs.  I'm currently using WordPress, which out of the box supports LaTeX, but it's a bit of a nuisance.  The biggest problem is that math mode is triggered by `latex [your math here]` rather than `[your math here]`; typing LaTeX over and over again can get really cumbersome.  Additionally, there doesn't appear to be support for the various standard LaTeX environments (I would particularly like the proof environment), and I don't see any way to create diagrams.

Is there a more elegant way to handle all of this, inside or outside WordPress?

Comment: use `tex4ht` with some static site generator, such as `Jekyll`. see https://github.com/michal-h21/jekyll4ht

Comment: If you use the `QuickLaTeX` plugin for WordPress, you can mark a whole page as `[latexpage]` and the MathJaX etc. commands are recognized. It's even possible to load tikz etc. content

Comment: Another option is [LaTeX2HTML5](http://latex2html5.com/), which supports proof environments and (rather limited, in my opinion)  interactive diagrams using pstricks. It's intended for web-based textbooks, so I don't know how well it adapts to a blog setting.

Comment: »WordPress, which out of the box supports Latex« this is not true for selfhosted WordPress blogs. You're probably talking about the publishing platform »wordpress.org«

Answer (score 0):

Just to share a basic LaTeX to WordPress converter (of mine) can be found here: http://mathtuition88.blogspot.sg/2015/12/latex-to-wordpress-converter.html

Change `$...$` to `$latex...$`

Additional conversions:

1. `\[...\ ]` to `$latex \displaystyle...$`
2. `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` to `$latex \begin{aligned}...$\end{aligned}`

As you can easily see, it is very basic with few features. I created it after experiencing the same frustrations as the above poster.